# Javascript - change element content when Radio input is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the content when a Radio input is unchecked? Is there a way to animate the transition when the content changes?

```js
function radioCheck(target) {
 radioElem = document.getElementById(target);
}

function statusChange(target) {
 label = document.getElementById(target);
 if (radioElem.checked) {
  label.innerHTML = "done";
 }
 else {
  label.innerHTML = "copy";
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="checkfield" id="radio-1"  onchange="radioCheck('radio-1');statusChange('label-1');"/><label for="radio-1" id="label-1">copy</label>
     <input type="radio" name="checkfield" id="radio-2"  onchange="radioCheck('radio-2');statusChange('label-2')"/><label for="radio-2" id="label-2">copy</label>
     <input type="radio" name="checkfield" id="radio-3"  onclick="radioCheck('radio-3');statusChange('label-3')"/><label for="radio-3" id="label-3">copy</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation 1**

- **`radCheck()`** passes Event Object

  - `rads` is a Live HTMLCollection

    - **`event.currentTarget`** references the `<form>`
    - **`.elements`** is a collection of all form controls
    - **`.checkfield`** narrows down collection to all form
      controls named checkfield
- **`for...of`** loop iterates through `rads` - `r` is current radio

  - Ternary: 
    ***if*** current radio is **`.checked`**:  status = "Done"
    ***else***: status = "Copy"
  - Find current radio **`.nextElementSibling`** (ie `<label>` after current radio)
    Set `<label>` **`.textContent`** to value of status (ie "Copy" or "Done")

This is done for each pair of radio and label

---

**Explanation 2**

- **`document.forms[0]`** - The first (and only in this instance) `<form>`
- **`.onchange`** - Register the `<form>` to the change event
- **`radCheck`** - Call the event handler

  ```js
  /*
  See Explanation 1
  */

  const radCheck = event => {
    const rads = event.currentTarget.elements.checkfield;
    for (let r of rads) {
      let status = r.checked ? "Done" : "Copy";
      r.nextElementSibling.textContent = status;
    }
  }

  /*
  See Explanation 2
  */

  document.forms[0].onchange = radCheck;
  ```

  ```html
  <form>
    <input id="radio-1" name="checkfield" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-1">Copy</label>
    <input id="radio-2" name="checkfield" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-2">Copy</label>
    <input id="radio-3" name="checkfield" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-3">Copy</label>
  </form>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```js
function radioCheck(target) {
 radioElem = document.getElementById(target);
}

const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label"); // added

function statusChange(target) {
 label = document.getElementById(target);
        labels.forEach(function(p){ // added
          p.innerHTML = "copy"; // added
        }); // added
 if (radioElem.checked) {
  label.innerHTML = "done";
 }
 else {
  label.innerHTML = "copy";
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="checkfield" id="radio-1"  onchange="radioCheck('radio-1');statusChange('label-1');"/><label for="radio-1" id="label-1">copy</label>
     <input type="radio" name="checkfield" id="radio-2"  onchange="radioCheck('radio-2');statusChange('label-2')"/><label for="radio-2" id="label-2">copy</label>
     <input type="radio" name="checkfield" id="radio-3"  onclick="radioCheck('radio-3');statusChange('label-3')"/><label for="radio-3" id="label-3">copy</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This strategy is very similar to the one taken in [@dgknca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581897/javascript-change-element-content-when-radio-input-is-unchecked#answer-55581932), but is generalized and cleaned up a bit from the initial question.

```js
// Add the event listener to each input
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', onRadioChange);
})

function onRadioChange(e) {
  // Set each label to the inital value
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
    if (input !== e.target) input.labels[0].innerHTML = 'copy'
  })
  
  // Set the selected input's label to the checked value
  e.target.labels[0].innerHTML = 'done'
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="checkfield" />
  <label for="input-1">copy</label>
  
  <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="checkfield" />
  <label for="input-2">copy</label>

  <input id="input-3" type="radio" name="checkfield" />
  <label for="input-3">copy</label>
</form>
```